# Automatically Mount SD card

Tags: mount, permissions

I have a beagleboard running Ubuntu. When it boots it does not automatically mount the MicroSD card so I mount it using `sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt/` which mounts it perfect. Then I want to upload a file using PHP and move it from the tmp location to the MicorSD card. I would like to do this using `move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "/mnt/$fileName"` but my Apache logs say permission denied. I tried to chmod mnt with 777 but this does not work.

What would be the best method to

A/ Automatically mount the SD card at boot

B/ Apply the correct permissions to allow PHP to move files to the sd card.

This machine will never see the web so I am not concerned about security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B/ try changing ownership to user running php

A/ add sdcard to /etc/fstab https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Answer (score 0):

Had to format the card to `ext` and chmod to 777. Fstab did fix the other issue however.