# eMMC replaced with SD, showing incorrect storage size

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, filesystem, sd-card

I'm attempting to get an SD card to mount on boot for permanent storage and I'm pretty sure I screwed it up. **This is my first time with Linux and I'm not a programmer.** I've never even partitioned anything before.

I'm running Lubuntu 22.04 on a Chromebook, which came with a 16gb eMMC drive.

After doing some research, I mounted my SD to root (which I assume is where I went wrong):

`sudo mount /dev/mmcblk1p1 /`

Then I got into /etc/fstab and added the following (with the appropriate whitespace and an extra newline at the bottom):

`/dev/mmcblk1p1 / ext2 defaults 0 0`

Things seemed fine.

However! Before I remounted the SD, running `df -h ~` showed this:

```
Filesystem     Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mmcblk0p2 15G  14G  0     100% /
```

Similarly, `df -h` showed all the usual drives, including **both** mmcblk0p2 (the eMMC) and mmcblk1p1 (the SD).

Imagine my horror when, after mounting the SD to root, I check `df -h ~` and it shows me this:

```
Filesystem     Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mmcblk1p1 15G  14G  0     100% /
```

mmcblk1p1 has 128gb.

mmcblk0p2 has also disappeared from the `df -h` result.

So, how badly did I mess this up? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You've not told us what release of Lubuntu, but your approach strikes me as strange... Why did you attempt to `mount` at `/` ??  That would cause your existing `/` to be *shadowed* and thus effects from that point would I'd expect to be *flaky* (had you prepared for this??).... so your approach either strikes me as *wrong*, or I'm missing something in what you're trying to do.  Is your Lubuntu installed? or are you trying to `mount` in order to install it as your provided details seem *wrong* to me.

Comment: @guiverc oop thanks it's 22.04, installed on the eMMC. Honestly I have no clue what I'm doing, I'm learning as I go – it's likely that I'm completely misunderstanding something. I just need the SD to be usable by the system, which it wasn't before. I got the idea after poking around on some forums, which I'll link in my next comment. BTW I'm using the command line because the login screen freezes due to a lack of space.

Comment: (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1794862) (https://askubuntu.com/questions/95391/how-do-i-mount-an-sd-card) (https://askubuntu.com/questions/773487/automatically-mount-sd-card) (https://superuser.com/questions/467753/how-to-mount-a-partition-on-the-root-directory-for-example-data) (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions)

Comment: You need to have free space in $HOME (your user directory; type `echo $HOME` in a terminal to see what I mean) for a GUI session to start & operate, if you have insufficient space you won't get past the greeter (ie. `sddm` for Lubuntu)... but you will be able to login & work at terminal. If your system is booted & running, do **not** cause that file-system to be shadowed (ie. your `sudo mount /dev/mmcblk1p1 /` could be risky/dangerous if you were booted & thus your system already had `/` mounted.. results after that command maybe *untrustworthy* unless you cleared caches etc.. or get corrupted